# is there some configuration wrong in IndentityServer4 configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

Consent page keep redirecting back to login page in Indentityserver4 asp.net core 2.2

i have tried different configuration on Identityservice and MVC client, but in vain

i have uploaded the code on github at below url
https://github.com/Dheerajmentor/IdentityServer4-Problem

MVC Client startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
             .AddCookie("Cookie")
             .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc",options=> {
                 options.Authority = "https://localhost:44398/";
                 options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                 options.ClientId = "mvc";
                 options.SaveTokens = true;
             });
        }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Identity server startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryClients(APPConfigure.GetClients())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(APPConfigure.GetIdentityResource())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(APPConfigure.GetAPIResources())
                .AddTestUsers(APPConfigure.GetUsers())
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();


        }
```

i expected after successfull signin it will redirect to consent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in else part
app.UseHttpsRedirection() ensures that you are always redirected to https and in development you run on http.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection()
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar issue. I am running in debug mode using https. Removing app.UseHttpsRedirection(); worked for me.